# Event target inherited by child doesn't effect parent React

Tags: css, reactjs, event-handling, styling, target

My question is basically how can I have a child style event affect the parent. Right now I'm using event target to change the style of a table cell I'm hovering over, but whenever I hover over a child with text in it the child changes but the parent does not which doesn't look very good. Here's my code.

```
hoverBackground = (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains(this.state.calendarNavi) || e.target.classList.contains(this.state.calendarNaviEmpty)) {
            e.target.style.background = 'darkgrey'
        } else {
            e.target.style.background = "#b1a18b"
            e.target.style.color = "white"
        }

    }
```

I've looked for answers for a while but I couldn't find one most people are trying to prevent the child from effecting the parent, but I'm having the opposite problem. I want the child to change the style of the parent and vise versa.

Here's the table data, I'm using Material Design Bootstrap for basic layouts:

```
<td key={d} day={`${d}`} dayName={`${currentWeekDay}`} month={`${this.month()}`} onMouseEnter={this.hoverBackground} onMouseLeave={this.hoverBackgroundExit} className={`calendar-day ${currentDay} ${currentWeek} railway`} style={currentStyle}>
                    <MDBContainer>
                        <MDBRow>
                            <MDBCol>
                                {d}
                            </MDBCol>
                        </MDBRow>
                    </MDBContainer>
                </td>
```

P.S. Sorry for the messy looking code, I still have to clean this component up a bit. Also I'm open to better ways of handling this hover event if anyone has suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I rubber ducked! The problem was using event.target vs using event.currentTarget